# How do you do fuzzy grouping in python?

Tags: python, comparison, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

I'm currently working in Python with a data frame with 5 columns. My end goal is to have my script produce an excel sheet that lists certain lines of my data based off of the following: I want to know when columns 1,2,3 and 4 are equal to each other AND the data in column 5 is similar. I've already concatenated my first 4 columns, and am now looking at a way to map the concatenated column to similar values that occur in column 5.

I've been looking into using fuzzywuzzy to do so, but am struggling with how exactly to structure my code. Is there a way to use fuzzywuzzy to group similar data in a single column, and then map that data to a different column?

Comment: Do you have any examples of code you have tried and need assistance with?

Comment: I haven't really gotten anything to work quite yet. I'm looking for help just structuring the code to start -- I've found a lot of examples for fuzzy mapping multiple columns together, but nothing on how to fuzzy group a single column's data together.

Comment: When you say single column, are you saying you want to compare say `col1 index 0` to `col1 index 1`?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Is there a base value you're comparing to, how do you determine your comparison?